# Group excel cells in POI and having the first row as "main"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use POI to generate an excel sheet. When grouping rows using

```
        curSheet.groupRow(firstRow, lastRow)
```

I noticed that the main Row that stays before collapsing is the last row of the grouping (the row with number lastRow).

How can I change it to first row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
      curSheet.setRowSumsBelow(false)
```